# on lifting elements in a tangent space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, singularity-theory, approximation-theory

Let X a normal integral scheme over a base field scheme, assumedd to be singular and an integer $n$
Let $\mathcal{O}=k[[t]]$, we consider the arc space $X(\mathcal{O})$ which is a $k$- pro-scheme and $k$-points $x$ and $y\in X(\mathcal {O})$ such that $x=y ~[t^{n}]$.
We also assume that over $X(F)$, the points factor through the smooth part of $X$.

In particular, it defines for example an element $t^{n}z\in T_{x}X(\mathcal{O}/t^{2n})$, under which conditions  could we lift this element to an element in $T_{x}X(\mathcal{O})$?

Comment: What is $F$? Is it the same as $k$?

Comment: F is the fraction field of $\mathcal{O}$